# Filter json string based on value and extract key

Tags: jq

I have the following json string:

```
{
  "lo": [
    "127.0.0.1",
    "::1"
  ],
  "ens5": [
    "10.77.23.18",
    "fe80::4dd:baff:fecb:ef91"
  ],
  "ens6": [
    "10.77.18.149",
    "fe80::445:b3ff:fe48:bd98"
  ]
}
```

From which I want to filter the key to the given value.

e.g. Given the string "fe80::4dd:baff:fecb:ef91" I want to get the value "ens5"

P.S I have no control over the format of the json string.

Comment: I know how to do this if it was a list using select filter. But not sure how to approach this for a map

Comment: Yea I can't find a valid duplicate, so I'll guess I'll post an answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
to_entries[] | select(.value[] | contains("fe80::4dd:baff:fecb:ef91")).key
```

Will log `.key` (`ens5` in the example), or nothing if the IP can't be found.

---

###### [Try it online](https://jqplay.org/s/clBy8gk4m1A)

Comment: Thankyou, this is perfect :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a "recursive search" - you can also use `paths()` + `strings`

```
paths(strings | select(. == "fe80::4dd:baff:fecb:ef91"))[-2]
```

https://jqplay.org/s/s4Dqorimh84